# Chrome extension : Prevent click in contentscript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have following in my `contentscript.js`

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event: MouseEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

}, false);
```

The listener is called but the click in not captured/prevented and is propagrated.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Use `window` instead of `document`, `mousedown` instead of `click`, and `true` instead of `false`. In rare cases it might be necessary to specify "run_at": "document_start" for the content script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the listener is attached to the document, I had to use the `capture` parameter to `preventDefault` while the event "bubbles" up.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
}, {capture: true});
```